# Vue JS if statement returns both outcomes

Tags: vue.js, if-statement

I am making a website with a login function. However, when you successfully log in, it tells you both that the login failed and that it succeeded. Here is the code that handles the login message:

```
log () {
  const self = this
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.regname, this.passname).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.code, error.message)
  })
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    const huser = !!user
    if (huser === true) {
      self.$router.push('/firstlogged')
      self.$q.notify({
        color: 'positive',
        spinner: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        progress: true,
        message: 'Login Success!',
        actions: [
          { label: 'Dismiss', color: 'white', handler: () => { /* ... */ } }
        ]
      })
    } else if (huser === false) {
      self.$q.notify({
        timeout: 5000,
        progress: true,
        color: 'negative',
        message: 'Login Failed, check your input',
        actions: [
          { label: 'Dismiss', color: 'white', handler: () => { /* ... */ } }
        ]
      })
    }
  })
},
```

Obviously, it should only send one of these messages. It does however work if you put in the wrong login details. Any fixes to this?

Comment: @PatrickArtner the double exclamation mark converts it into a boolean

Comment: What is !!user?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I tried this, but it changed nothing

Comment: which type `user` is ? if it's a empty object/array `!!user` is going to be `true`